# getting hash values while trying to increment the value inside for loop in a java program

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to get the output of 8 through this loop condition but I am getting this value instead:

> -2147483648

```java
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int p = 2; 
        int j=5; 
        for (int i = p; i < j; i++) {
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(j);
    } 
}
```

Why is it happening and where do I need to look into?

Comment: `i<j;` is reevaluated for each iteration.  In each iteration you are also incrementing `j` - I am not understanding what logic you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also find out what the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is.  `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`

Comment: if we have 2 values i need to increment the j value by the difference of the i th and jth value thats what i have tried to .. but the logic is not correct it seems

Comment: Try using a new variable to hold this `calculated` value

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you're incrementing both `i` and `j`.  That means that `i < j` is going to be true for several iterations.

Eventually, `j` reaches the largest possible `int`; which means that the next time you increment it, it will flip to the smallest possible `int`.  Finally, it's less than `i`, so the loop will break.  Therefore, the final value of `j`, at the end of your program, is the smallest possible `int`, which is `-2147483648`.

Comment: class Test1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int p = 2; 
        int j=5; 
        for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(j);
    } 
}

i got the desired output 8 by changing the values p and j into 2 and 5 respectively inside for loop .. so i'm confused that how can we get the values from the assigned variables to inside the for loop? it would be really helpful if you explained this one too